# Redux toolkit: Have two slices reference each other's actions in extraReducers?

Tags: redux-toolkit

I would like two different slices to cross-reference each other's actions like so:

```
const sliceA = createSlice({
    name: "sliceA",
    initialState: null,
    reducers: {
        someReducer: (state, action) => {
            // do something
        },
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [sliceB.actions.anotherReducer]: (state, action) => {
            // do something
        },
    },
});

const sliceB = createSlice({
    name: "sliceB",
    initialState: null,
    reducers: {
        anotherReducer: (state, action) => {
            // do something else
        },
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [sliceA.actions.someReducer]: (state, action) => {
            // do something else
        },
    },
});
```

The problem is that I receive the error that sliceB is undefined when trying to set the extraReducers for sliceA.

I would like to keep the slices separate for clarity, but that *some* of their actions affect each other.

**What is a good way to achieve that?**

Comment: Shouldn't you define sliceB first?

Comment: @cherry3 but then I have an error in sliceB, saying that sliceA is undefined.

Comment: Place them in their own file and use import?

Answer (score 6):

You have to resolve the circular dependency between the slices by factoring out the creation for the one of the actions into a createActions call that both createSlice calls can reference as extraReducers without their definition being circular.

also note your action naming, and then the line here, is misleading:
`[sliceA.actions.someReducer]: (state, action) => {`

You createSlice is making both *actions* and *reducers*, so use a name for the action that doesn't imply it's a reducer.

use createAction: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction

See circular ref notes here: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#exporting-and-using-slices

```
const actionOnAThatAffectsB = createAction('B_ACTION_NAME', function prepare(text) {
  // this function is an optional parameter to createAction.
  // only use it if you want to add to the eventual payload.
  return {
    payload: {
      text,
      id: nanoid(),
      createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
    }
  }
})

const sliceB = createSlice({
    name: "sliceB",
    initialState: null,
    reducers: {
        actionOnBThatAffectsA: (state, action) => {
            // do main stuff on A
        },
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [sliceA.actions.someAction]: (state, action) => {
            // do other stuff.
        },
    },
});

const sliceA = createSlice({
    name: "sliceA",
    initialState: null,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: {
        [sliceB.actions.actionOnBThatAffectsA]: (state, action) => {
            // do extra stuff on A
        },
        [actionOnAThatAffectsB]: (state, action) => {
            // you can't create the *action* here with createSlice's default creation through the reducers{} parameter — since that leads to a circular reference during creation.
            // You *are* creating the *reducer* itself here, though.
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: Can you give a code example of how to achieve it based on my example? I know what I have to do, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I've updated it. (note: I haven't tried to run that code.) I've found the redux-toolkit docs be a bit lacklustre for more complicated things like what you're doing—so consider falling back to the main redux docs when they're unclear.